# Oauth error in flickraw gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth-2.0, flickr

I'm using flickraw gem to get links to photos in my flickr profile and display them on my blog. I'm following the documentation on github but its throwing the following error

```
Processing by StaticPagesController#index as HTML
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 916ms

FlickRaw::OAuthClient::FailedResponse - FlickRaw::OAuthCli
flickraw (0.9.8) lib/flickraw/oauth.rb:156:in `post'
flickraw (0.9.8) lib/flickraw/oauth.rb:92:in `post_form'
flickraw (0.9.8) lib/flickraw/api.rb:58:in `call'
flickraw (0.9.8) lib/flickraw/api.rb:48:in `initialize'
flickraw (0.9.8) lib/flickraw.rb:20:in `flickr'
app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb:6:in `index'
```

I have the following code in my controller

```
  class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
    def index
      token = flickr.get_request_token
      auth_url = token['oauth_authorize_url']
      puts "Open this url in your process to complete the authication process : #{auth_url}"
      puts "Copy here the number given when you complete the process."
      verify = gets.strip

      begin
        flickr.get_access_token(token['oauth_token'], token['oauth_token_secret'], verify)
        login = flickr.test.login
        puts "You are now authenticated as #{login.username}"
      rescue FlickRaw::FailedResponse => e
        puts "Authentication failed : #{e.msg}"
      end
    flickr.photos.search(user_id: "130879534@N07")
  end
end
```

Following is my Flickraw.rb

```
FlickRaw.secure = false
FlickRaw.api_key = "<api key>"
FlickRaw.shared_secret = "<secret>"
```

Comment: I hope that isn't your actual api key? Don't want that floating around the internet!

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](https://github.com/hanklords/flickraw#authentication) it looks like your auth flow should look like this:

```
FlickRaw.api_key="... Your API key ..."
FlickRaw.shared_secret="... Your shared secret ..."

token = flickr.get_request_token
auth_url = flickr.get_authorize_url(token['oauth_token'], :perms => 'delete')

puts "Open this url in your process to complete the authication process : #{auth_url}"
puts "Copy here the number given when you complete the process."
verify = gets.strip

begin
  flickr.get_access_token(token['oauth_token'], token['oauth_token_secret'], verify)
  login = flickr.test.login
  puts "You are now authenticated as #{login.username} with token #{flickr.access_token} and secret #{flickr.access_secret}"
rescue FlickRaw::FailedResponse => e
  puts "Authentication failed : #{e.msg}"
end
```

Comment: This line looks different? `auth_url = flickr.get_authorize_url(token['oauth_token'], :perms => 'delete')`

Comment: Actually I'm getting the error on this line `token = flickr.get_request_token` . when I check the value of token in the console provided by the better_errors gem, its nil

Comment: Is `flickraw.rb` located in `config/initializers` ?

Comment: Try having all the code in the controller to begin with (you can always move code to an initializer) -- See my update

Comment: Also, what version of flickraw are you using?

Comment: I tried putting the code from initializer to my controller but it doesn't work. I'm using flickraw-0.9.8